# Why am I getting an "assignment from incompatible pointer type" error?

Tags: c, pointers

I keep getting this error, but cannot figure out why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my stock.h file.

```
typedef struct stock {

char *stockSymbol;
float closingSharePrice;
float openingSharePrice;
int numberOfShares;
float (* getPrice) (void * S);
float (* getTotalDollarAmount) (void * S);
float (* getPercentChange) (void * S);
char * (* toString)(void * S);

 } stock_t; 

float returnPrice (stock_t *S);
float returnTotal (stock_t *S);
float returnPercentChange (stock_t *S);
char * returnString (stock_t *S);
```

And this is my stocks.c file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stocks.h"

float returnPrice (stock_t *S) {

S->getPrice = returnPrice;

    }
```

It is in the .c file in the line where I set the getPrice pointer equal to the returnPrice function and I get the error. How should I define assign getPrice so that it points to the returnPrice function? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The prototype that `setPrice` expects is `float (* getPrice) (void * S);` which means that `setPrice` expects the argument to the function to accept a pointer to any data type. However, your `returnPrice` method is more restrictive as `float returnPrice (stock_t *S)` so it only works with/expects a `stock_t*` as an argument and therefore does not meet the criteria for a `setPrice` pointer.

You would need to declare `float returnPrice (void *S)` and then cast `S` inside the function for it to work correctly. Or cast the function pointer itself.

```
typedef float (*GetPriceFunction) (void * S);

typedef struct stock 
{
    GetPriceFunction getPrice;
}

S->getPrice = (GetPriceFunction)returnPrice;
```

Answer (score 1):

`float (*) (void*)` and `float (*) (stock_t*)` are different types, hence the complaint.

To define your function you can use e.g. this syntax:

```
typedef struct stock stock_t;
struct stock {
   ...
   float (* getPrice) (stock_t * S);
   ...
};
```

Do not use `void*` and casts unless you absolutely have to. In this case you don't have to. Other answers tell you to go ahead and use `void*`. I respectfully submit that this is ill-advised.

I'm not sure why you would do the function pointer assignment at the place you do. This is probably wrong, though has nothing to do with the compiler message.

Comment: This is for a homework assignment where my professor wants us to use pointers to functions with void pointers. We are supposed to get function to point to code that will carry out certain functions.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `S->getPrice` is a pointer to a `float(void *)`, but `returnPrice` is a `float(stock_t *)`. Those are not the same, nor are they compatible.

You could fix it by changing the function signature:

```
float returnPrice(void * p)
{ 
    stock_t * S = p;
    S->getPrice = &returnPrice;
}
```